# Emacs mode line shows AC is on but no autocomplete is happening

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, clojure

I have freshly installed `auto-complete` `popup` and `ac-nrepl` from elpa. When I enter a clojure buffer in emacs, the `AC` indicates auto-complete is turned on. But no matter what I type or do in the buffer, I cannot get autocomplete to do anything. I'v been troubleshooting this for awhile, any pointers? I have this in my emacs startup as well:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d")
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(ac-config-default)

(package-initialize)
(require 'auto-complete)

(require 'ac-nrepl)
(add-hook 'cider-repl-mode-hook 'ac-nrepl-setup)
(add-hook 'cider-mode-hook 'ac-nrepl-setup)

(eval-after-load "auto-complete" '(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'cider-repl-mode))

(defun set-auto-complete-as-completion-at-point-function ()
  (setq completion-at-point-functions '(auto-complete)))
(add-hook 'auto-complete-mode-hook 'set-auto-complete-as-completion-at-point-function)

(add-hook 'cider-repl-mode-hook 'set-auto-complete-as-completion-at-point-function)
(add-hook 'cider-mode-hook 'set-auto-complete-as-completion-at-point-function)
```

Comment: Btw, you should check out `company-mode`. As noted in cider's docs it's the completion framework that's recommended for use with cider (and it will work out of the box, no extra packages required).

Comment: @BozhidarBatsov I'm reading this page: https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider but it doesn't say (nor can I find) how to enable "company-capf" if you are not using emacs 24.4 (i'm on 24.3) and it appears you must enable that to get the built-in company mode support in cider.

Comment: It's just a regular `company-mode` backend. You'll have to do something like `(push 'company-capf company-backends)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try add `cider-mode` to `ac-modes` instead of `cider-repl-mode`:

```
  (add-to-list 'ac-modes 'cider-mode)
```

Comment: Do you have your config on Github? Oh, I see you use `auto-complete` as `completion-at-point-functions`, so you might also need `(setq tab-always-indent 'complete)`.